# local uaa docker image container not starting in windows docker

Tags: docker

I have built a local uaa docker image and tried to run in local.
But I am getting this error when I am trying to start the docker image.
I built the docker image via this below command and the build is successful too.

`docker build -t uaa-local --build-arg uaa_yml_name=local.yml .`

when I am trying to run the local uaa docker image, I am getting this below error. What I am doing wrong

Content of DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre

ARG uaa_yml_name=local.yml

ENV UAA_CONFIG_PATH /uaa
ENV CATALINA_HOME /tomcat

ADD run.sh /tmp/
ADD conf/$uaa_yml_name /uaa/uaa.yml
RUN chmod +x /tmp/run.sh

RUN wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.57/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.57.tar.gz


RUN tar zxf apache-tomcat-8.5.57.tar.gz
RUN rm apache-tomcat-8.5.57.tar.gz

RUN mkdir /tomcat
RUN mv apache-tomcat-8.5.57/* /tomcat
RUN rm -rf /tomcat/webapps/*

ADD dist/cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-74.22.0.war /tomcat/webapps/
RUN mv /tomcat/webapps/cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-74.22.0.war /tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

RUN mkdir -p /tomcat/webapps/ROOT && cd /tomcat/webapps/ROOT && unzip ../ROOT.war
ADD conf/log4j2.properties /tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.properties
RUN rm -rf /tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/tmp/run.sh"]
```

[image]

On further investigation I think it is looking for run.sh file in the /tmp/ folder which is added on line 5 in Dockerfile..but when I checked for the file in /tmp/ folder it is not there..Is it because of that?And how to resolve that? I already have the run.sh in my current folder.

Comment: what's in the Dockerfile?

Comment: added it in the question

Comment: Did you see [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory-in-docker) article?

Comment: I tried their solution dos2unix.exe Dockerfile but after the correction..my docker build is failing - => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:11-jre...so reverted back to original Dockerfile